Can't Update a safe through CLI
I'm trying to update my safe from 1.3.0 to 1.4.1 but every time I try to update it through the CLI it says "1.3.0 cannot be updated (yet)". I tried changing the Master Copy to that of 1.4.1 too and I got the same error, is there a way to do this?

The deployment script from v1.3.0 to v1.4.1 is still a work in progress. You can track the progress here: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-cli/issues/251. In the meantime you can deploy an instance of the migration contract and use it to upgrade your safe. Please note however that this option is quite technical, so please only do it if you absolutely know what you are doing! If not it might be safer to wait for the update, if you can.
Hope it helps; Best, Louis
