send_erc20 tx on safe CLI not working on CELO
Cannot find enough owners to sign. 6 missing
Also, sending the tx on the UI nor updating from v1.3.0 are working


Hi Mateo! Have you made sure to have configured all the corresponding owners for this safe? https://docs.safe.global/advanced/cli-reference/common-commands#from-private-key. Updating from v1.3.0 is indeed not supported yet. You can find more information on this in a previous answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/163657/cant-update-a-safe-through-cli

oh, do I really need to set every owner on my cli for it? - I won't have access of 6 private keys for that...
also as a workaround I tried to change the threshold but it's not being successful either...

anyway I don't seem to be able to use any simple method for this contract...

Yes, you will have to load at least enough owners to reach the threshold.

can you suggest me a proper way to load all owners without holding their private keys, this totally sounds counterintuitive with the whole idea of having a multisig - I was thinking of having a cloud instance with the CLI running so every owner can load their key without me seeing them.. but would love your feedback before trying it out
.... Also, another question - would updating the contract solve this..? we just really need to get some funds out to a fresh (and new) safe

This will not be possible, as the CLI is a tool for performing common operations locally. You could try other ways to interact with your safe; I guess that it is not possible via app.safe.global, so you could try by using Safe Transaction Service: first create a transaction https://docs.safe.global/core-api/transaction-service-reference#Create-Multisig-Transaction and then confirm it https://docs.safe.global/core-api/transaction-service-reference#Confirm-Multisig-Transaction What network are you using?

thanks for the help @Louis-SafeCoreTeam - the network is CELO

I'm having trouble building the tx, it tells me the contractTransactionHash does not match, I'll show you a snippet of what I'm sending https://gist.github.com/mateodaza/030638c14b684af429efdfbb93d7284c any idea?

I will check with the team. At first glance I would suggest using viem or ethers instead of web3; in the meantime you could also try to use the transaction builder to get the transaction data: https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40841-transaction-builder. Add the address of the ERC20 token you want to transfer and the amount before clicking the "Download" button on the top-right of the screen. Let me know if it worked!

Yeah the transaction builder was my first approach... still didn't work - thanks a lot anyway
